# log4net, can't get it working with .net 4.0 mvc app

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Trying to get log4net setup for .net 4.0 asp.net mvc2 app. I have bare minimum configuration but nothing is getting logged. Am I missing something?

- referencing log4net 1.2.10 released version dll
- added in sections

```xml
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
```

- added section

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
        <conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="c:\\example.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="Console" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

- trying to log message with          `log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("global").Error("test error");`

But there is nothing getting logged and no error. Tried lot of config variations like only console, only rollingfile, to file appender only. but nothing works. And yes it's .net 4.0 full project not client profile.

What could be wrong in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you start log4net?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    ...
}
```